# Update global variable from while loop

Tags: bash, shell

Having trouble updating my global variable in this shell script.
I have read that the variables inside the loops run on a sub shell. Can someone clarify how this works and what steps I should take.

```
USER_NonRecursiveSum=0.0

while [ $lineCount -le $(($USER_Num)) ] 
do
    thisTime="$STimeDuration.$NTimeDuration"
    USER_NonRecursiveSum=`echo "$USER_NonRecursiveSum + $thisTime" | bc`
done
```

Comment: Your sample code can't even run. Please provide a minimal reproducible sample code to illustrate your problem.

Comment: You are probably piping input in to this loop (which you haven't shown). Loops don't necessarily run in a subshell, but commands in a pipeline do. You can solve this by feeding your loop input from a redirection. Either a process substitution: `while ... done < <(my-cmd)`, or a file: `while ... done < myfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That *particular* style of loop does not run in a sub-shell, it will update the variable just fine. You can see that in the following code, equivalent to yours other than adding things that you haven't included in the question:

```sh
USER_NonRecursiveSum=0

((USER_Num = 4)) # Add this to set loop limit.
((lineCount = 1)) # Add this to set loop control variable initial value.

while [ $lineCount -le $(($USER_Num)) ]
do
    thisTime="1.2" # Modify this to provide specific thing to add.

    USER_NonRecursiveSum=`echo "$USER_NonRecursiveSum + $thisTime" | bc`

    (( lineCount += 1)) # Add this to limit loop.
done

echo ${USER_NonRecursiveSum} # Add this so we can see the final value.
```

That loop runs four times and adds `1.2` each time to the value starting at zero, and you can see it ends up as `4.8` after the loop is done.

While the `echo` command *does* run in a sub-shell, that's not an issue as the backticks explicitly *capture* the output from it and "deliver" it to the current shell.

Comment: Ok, will do some further debugging.

Comment: @jTruBela One thing I'd recommend is running your script through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) and fixing what it points out. It can also be helpful to put `set -x` before a problem section to turn on execution tracing (and `set +x` at the end to turn tracing off).